# LINQ to SQL - Format a string before saving?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, string, formatting, properties

I'm trying to convert an existing (non-LINQ to SQL) class into a LINQ to SQL entity class which has an existing (db column) property like:

```
public string MyString
{
    get { return myString; }
    set { myString = FormatMyString(value); }
}
```

**Is there a way to do this sort of processing on the value of entity class property before saving?**

Should I use some sort of an entity-level saving event in which to do my formatting (if that will even work)?

I know LINQ to SQL provides validation and there are generated `On...Changing()` partial methods which provide access to the new value, *by value (not by ref)*, but none of those methods seem to provide a way to ***actually modify/format the value*** while it is being set.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using On...Changed()? It fires after the property value has changed. There you can check its value and update it using the FormatString.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up (got sidetracked).  Yes, this is the method I used, thanks!  What I hadn't thought of (since I'm still a L2S noob), is that in On...Changed(), you have access to the private member variable, named "_PropertyName" by the entity designer, which you can format and change without recursively triggering the OnChanging/OnChanging events.  Thanks again.